# Return data from value to Object Vuejs - Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a blade html table. In each row i have a value that i need to save in a Vue.js object to make my update function.

This is my code :

```
@foreach($users as user)
    <input class="hidden" value="{{$user->id}}"
           v-model="upload.id">
@endforeach
```

I need it to be saved in upload.id
thank you

Comment: so, what's the problem? i think it correct what you're providing

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is in a vue component? Don't use foreach

You need v-for

```
<template>
  <div v-for="user in users">
    <input class="hidden" :value="user.id" v-model="upload.id" />
  </div>
</template>
```